# GoogleSheets API:"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "Number" at 'data.values[0]': Cannot find field

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to copy contents of a spreadsheet into another spreadsheet but the error keeps popping up. 
Could you help to figure out why is it not copying over the data from one sheet to the other?
This is the dummy data I am experimenting on in the original sheet:

```
1   CHANGED London 
2   5   Budapest
3   4   Prague
4   11  Madrid
4   11  Madrid
```

This is how the destination sheet looks like:

```
2   5   Budapest
2   5   Budapest
2   5   Budapest
```

This is part of the error I get:

```
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "Weather" at 'data.values[0]': Cannot find field.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "City" at 'data.values[0]': Cannot find field.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "Number" at 'data.values[1]': Cannot find field.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "Weather" at 'data.values[1]': Cannot find field.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "City" at 'data.values[1]': Cannot find field.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "Number" at 'data.values[2]': Cannot find field.
```

And this is the script:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from pprint import pprint
from googleapiclient import discovery
scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope )
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

LT = client.open("LetsTry").sheet1
LT_data = LT.get_all_records()
NQ_all = client.open("NQ_all").sheet1
NQ_all_data = NQ_all.get_all_records()

service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
spreadsheetId = 'xyz'
range = 'Sheet1!A1:C11'
body = {
    'values': LT_data
}
result = service.spreadsheets().values().append(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, 
    range = range,
    valueInputOption= 'RAW',
    body=body).execute()
print('{0} cells updated.'.format(result.get('updatedCells')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

In your script, the values retrieved by `LT_data = LT.get_all_records()` are used to the request body of the method of spreadsheets.values.append in Sheets API. In this case of `LT_data`, the retrieved value is JSON object. But `values` of the request body is required to be 2 dimensional array. I think that the reason of your error message is this.

In order to avoid this error, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
LT_data = LT.get_all_records()
```

To:

```
LT_data = LT.get_all_values()
```

- The value retrieved by `get_all_values()` is 2 dimensional array. So in this case, it can be used for `body = {'values': LT_data}`.

#### Note:

- This answer supposes that you have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using gspread and googleapis for python with the service account.
- In your case, the Spreadsheets of `client.open("LetsTry")` and `spreadsheetId = 'xyz'` are required to be able to be accessed with the service account. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)
- [get_all_records()](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_all_records#gspread.models.Worksheet.get_all_records)
- [get_all_values()](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_all_values#gspread.models.Worksheet.get_all_values)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you !!! It did solve my issue and now it runs perfectly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your super useful and descriptive answer!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I recognized that it's because of encoding.
I just set all data to **utf8** and the error is fixed.

```
utf8_encode($yourValue);
```

Here is the utf encoding :
https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.utf8-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because of sending some "null" values. I solved by changing all the null values by empty string.